# How to make my while loop restart with a counter

Tags: python

I want to make a counter that counts down and restarts the loop when it reaches `0` like a game and makes `mr_krabs2` spawn where he was at the beginning.

```py
# Graphing frame 3.
win3 = GraphWin('Frame.3', 640, 360)
mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), 
r"\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png")
win3.setBackground("lightblue")      
# Drawing the inserted images.
mr_krabs2.draw(win3)   
# X and Y Variables.
x = 0.0
y = 0.0   
while True:
    key = win3.getKey()    
    if key == "w":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        y = y + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")   
    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        y = y - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")    
    if key == "a":
        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        x = x + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n") 
    if key == "d":
        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        x = x - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    # Hitbox for the destination.
    if (x < (59) and
        x > (52) and
        y < (4) and
        y > (-6)):
        time.sleep(5)
        win3.close()
        break
```

Comment: Put all the code inside a loop.

Comment: can u give a example where the counter would start and how big is your step size each iteration ?

Comment: I'll try that thanks. The counter would start at 60 seconds and I don't know what step size is. @gerdadiegandalfziege

Answer (score 2):

**All thanks to gerda die gandalfziega.**

```
from time import perf_counter

#Graphing frame 3
win3 = GraphWin('Frame.3', 640, 360)
mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), 
r"\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png")
win3.setBackground("lightblue")      
**Drawing the inserted images.**
mr_krabs2.draw(win3)   
# X and Y Variables.
x = 0.0
y = 0.0

start = perf_counter() # Get the current time this line is executed
while True:
    key = win3.getKey()  
        
    if perf_counter()-start >= 60:

        mr_krabs2.undraw()
        mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), r"\Users\leila\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png")
        mr_krabs2.draw(win3)
        start = start + 60 **Adds 60 seconds to reset the krab.**
                                  
    if key == "w":

        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        y = y + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")

    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        y = y - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")

    if key == "a":

        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        x = x + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")

    if key == "d":

        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        x = x - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
```

Comment: to add a comment to the code in an answer don't use **text** simply use a "#"

Answer (score 0):

i replaced while true with for loop that will run 100 times, you can change it

```
# Graphing frame 3.
win3 = GraphWin('Frame.3', 640, 360)
mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), 
r"\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png")
win3.setBackground("lightblue")      
# Drawing the inserted images.
mr_krabs2.draw(win3)   
# X and Y Variables.
x = 0.0
y = 0.0   
for i in range(100):
    key = win3.getKey()    
    if key == "w":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        y = y + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")   
    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        y = y - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")    
    if key == "a":
        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        x = x + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n") 
    if key == "d":
        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        x = x - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    # Hitbox for the destination.
    if (x < (59) and
        x > (52) and
        y < (4) and
        y > (-6)):
        time.sleep(5)
        win3.close()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would do it so the loop stops after 60 seconds

```
from time import perf_counter

# Graphing frame 3.
win3 = GraphWin('Frame.3', 640, 360)
mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), 
r"\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png")
win3.setBackground("lightblue")      
# Drawing the inserted images.
mr_krabs2.draw(win3)   
# X and Y Variables.
x = 0.0
y = 0.0   
start = perf_counter() # get the current time this line is executed
while perf_counter()-start <60: # This line check if the time difference between the current time and the starting time is smaller then 60 seconds
    key = win3.getKey()    
    if key == "w":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        y = y + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")   
    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        y = y - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")    
    if key == "a":
        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        x = x + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n") 
    if key == "d":
        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        x = x - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    # Hitbox for the destination.
    if (x < (59) and
        x > (52) and
        y < (4) and
        y > (-6)):
        time.sleep(5)
        win3.close()
        break
```

**EDIT2:**

```
from time import perf_counter

# Graphing frame 3.
win3 = GraphWin('Frame.3', 640, 360)
mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), 
r"\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png")
win3.setBackground("lightblue")      
# Drawing the inserted images.
mr_krabs2.draw(win3)   
# X and Y Variables.
x = 0.0
y = 0.0   
start = perf_counter() # get the current time this line is executed
while  # This line check if the time difference between the current time and the starting time is smaller then 60 seconds
    
    if perf_counter()-start >=60:
       mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), 
       win3.setBackground("lightblue")      
       # Drawing the inserted images.
       mr_krabs2.draw(win3)  
                   
    key = win3.getKey()    
    if key == "w":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        y = y + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")   
    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        y = y - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")    
    if key == "a":
        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        x = x + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n") 
    if key == "d":
        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        x = x - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    # Hitbox for the destination.
    if (x < (59) and
        x > (52) and
        y < (4) and
        y > (-6)):
        time.sleep(5)
        win3.close()
        break
```

Comment: Kept giving me a invalid syntax at the import perf_counter().

Comment: sry those brackets at the import where wrong I updated the code

Comment: It worked but it only stops the loop it doesn't restart it or make the Krab respawn where he was.

Comment: do u have a function where u can set the position of the krab like set_pos or move_to(x,y) ?

Comment: Yes. mr_krabs2 = Image(Point(600, 315), r"\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Mr.Krabs2.png") That's his position.

Comment: try the edit 2 it updated it

Comment: It works perfectly after I change the while True: and put mr_krabs.undraw() but after 60 seconds it doesn't stop undrawing and drawing.

Comment: I forgot to reset the start variable. I updated the code

Comment: What if we do a 60 second timer and if it's 0 it undraws and draws the krab but it also adds 60 seconds so it doesn't keep drawing.

Comment: yea that would work